# C# IBM MQ client sending my own messageId

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am sending an MQ message and getting a messageID and correlationID back in return as expected, and I can capture the response from specific message that I send using the messageID returned by the MQ server.

I put my application into a load testing tool and I saw that in some cases the messageID returned by the queue manager was the same as a previous message, and in these cases the app failed to read the next message with the same messageID.

I'm not the owner of the queue manager and the response from the admin was "created your own message id".

Can I do that? Does the messageID need to have a specific format?

This is my code :

```
            message = strInputMsg;
            queueMessage = new MQMessage();
            queueMessage.WriteString(message);
            queueMessage.Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            queueMessage.Expiry = timeOutExpiry;
            queueMessage.ReplyToQueueName = QueueNameExpiry;
            queuePutMessageOptions = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            queuePutMessageOptions.Options =       MQC.MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID;
            queue.Put(queueMessage, queuePutMessageOptions);
            bytReturn = queueMessage.MessageId;
```

So can I set the MessageID property to my own message ID value before I send the message, like the below?

```
queueMessage.MessageId = myOwnMessageId
```

Comment: I would recommend against generating your own message ID. The best practice is to copy the request Message ID to the response Correlation ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that the code sets the message ID explicitly but your code appears to not reuse the MQMD structure which is how that normally happens.  It is more likely based on your description and code provided that the load testing tool is replaying the same messages multiple times and preserving the Message ID while doing so.

If MQ is allowed to set the Message ID it guarantees this to be unique within the queue manager for IDs that it generates.  It does not guarantee a GUID across many queue managers but does attempt to ensure no collisions by including 12 characters of the QMgr name in the Message ID.  So although we have no information as to which load testing tool is being used and if it employs message replay, that possibility seems much more likely than that MQ has a bug that duplicates message IDs during execution of the .Net `MQMessage()` class constructor.

Please see:
[MQMessage.NET class](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm) which says "Creates an MQMessage object with default message descriptor information..." Of course, the default MQMD causes the QMgr to generate the Message ID.

[MQMD - MsgId (MQBYTE24)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097550_.htm) which explains in a note at the bottom how MsgID is made to be unique and in the body how it can be controlled by the application putting the messages.